# Can we able to receive notify-keyspace-events of aws elasticache redis to aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

Is there any way, we can receive `notifiy-keyspace-events` of **AWS ElasticCache-Redis** to **aws-lambda** function?